# Methods to compile, run and output c# code in a Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I was wondering whether it was possible to compile and run code in a Xamarin app. I currently have a text editor in c# and I would like it to be able to compile and run, to output c# code you put in the editor. I've seen this done in mobile apps like "dCoder" but i'm not sure if they were done in Xamarin. If someone would like to say if this is possible, and if so how, and if not how apps like dCoder do it. I've looked online but couldn't really find anything on it, if somebody could help with telling me how to do this it would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to write a C# compiler as a Xamarin app? Theoretically it should be doable. At the end of the day, it is just a read operation (for the sourcecode and any linked files) and a write opeartion (for the finished binary, intermediate code or whatever comes out). That means the Right System should be not much an issue. Of course there can be special handling for a App creating a **executeable** file in the OS. Writing a programm that downloads a virus would be a surefire way to gete around weak automatic antivirus checks.

Comment: I managed to cobble together a PHP Development Environment with nothing but WAMP, limited userrights, a 300 MiB memory contingent and notepad. Granted, I ended up using PHP for the Syntax highlighting. Also I would really not advise it. A lot of things you can do are too much trouble to be worth it.

Comment: @Christopher I've been looking over it and I think i'm going to try doing it with Roslyn to compile and parse the code and Reflection to run it in the app. Do you think this would be a viable way of doing it, so that when a button in the app would be pressed it would grab the text in the text box, and then output the code.

Comment: As I said, if there is any issue it is if you are allowed to write binary/application data from an App. Right Systems can be a lot more stringent with Executeable formats. You should look if apps can download other apps of the target format. For the right system it will not mater if the file was created from user input, downaloded or just stored in a constant all along - only that it is a app that tries to write something that can be executed.

Comment: @Christopher Ah, I see, well either way I haven't really made any headway so far figuring out how to do it in the first place let alone whether the app allowed.